# How to convert an exclusive range to inclusive range in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, range

I have an exclusive range of integers, e.g.

```
range = 1000...10001
```

I would rather work with inclusive ranges all the way, but the reason I have this is because when I tell ActiveRecord to store an inclusive range in PostgreSQL, I get the exclusive version when I query it back.

I want to convert it into an inclusive range, e.g. `1000..10000`.

I'm doing:

```
(range.begin)..(range.end-1)
```

However it feels clunky and un-ruby-ish.

My whole API relies on passing ranges, but I'm also considering storying 2 values or storing an array in Postgres instead of a range.

Is there a better way to do this?

---

**Edit (some clarifications)**

I want to do this as efficiently as possible, given the large difference between the ranges

My use case is to use the begin and end part of the ranges. I'm not actually iterating over them or checking inclusion. I just thought that a ruby range is a nice way to represent the actual range for e.g. displaying a price ($ 1.000 - $ 10.000)

Comment: `Range` has a constructor `Range.new(begin,end,exclude_end=false)`, however I'm not sure if this would helpful to you. Other than that, you could define your own `RangeUtils.to_inclusive(range)`,but that would only work for integers. Why do you want to work strictly with inclusive ranges? Aren't they functionally equivalent?

Comment: My use case is to use the `begin` and `end` part of the ranges. I'm not actually iterating over them or checking inclusion. I just thought that a ruby range is a nice way to represent the actual range for e.g. displaying a price ($ 1.000 - $ 10.000)

Comment: Might be related : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30611 As you said, it might be a better solution to store the 2 values and create the range dynamically. Use ranges in Ruby, use two integers (or decimals) and a boolean in Postgres.

Comment: @EricDuminil that is exactly my issue, thanks for pointing that issue, I wasn't able to find it on my own. It confirms that using ActiveRecord with Postgres ranges is not something very intuitive

Answer (score 4):

I would use [`Range#min`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Range.html#method-i-min) and [`Range#max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Range.html#method-i-max):

```
exclusive_range = (1000...10001)
inclusive_range = (exclusive_range.min..exclusive_range.max)
#=> 1000..10000
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I dismissed the thought of it because I thought it's going to run something like Array#min and max and compare all values. But on second thought now, I guess the algorithm of it might be more efficient in a range as it just needs to look at the ends. Do you know whether this is performant?